# What does [:] do?

Tags: python

```
return self.var[:]
```

What will that return?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python permits you to "slice" various container types; this is a shorthand notation for taking some subcollection of an ordered collection. For instance, if you have a list

```
foo = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and you want the second, third, and fourth elements, you can do:

```
foo[1:4]
```

If you omit one of the numbers in the slice, it defaults to the start of the list. So for instance

```
foo[1:] == [2,3,4,5]
foo[:4] == [1,2,3,4]
```

Naturally, if you omit both numbers in the slice you will get the entire list back! However, you will get a copy of the list instead of the original; in fact, this is the standard notation for copying a list. Note the difference:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = a
>>> b.append(5)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> b.append(5)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This occurs because `b = a` tells `b` to point to the same object as `a`, so appending to `b` is the same as appending to `a`. Copying the list `a` avoids this. Notice that this only runs one level of indirection deep -- if `a` contained a list, say, and you appended to that list in `b`, you would still change `a`.

By the way, there is an optional third argument to the slice, which is a *step* parameter -- it lets you move through the list in jumps of greater than 1. So you could write range(100)[0::2] for all the even numbers up to 100.

Comment: or you could write range(0, 100, 2)

Comment: also can be used to assign to a slice, eg `a[2:4] = [4,5,6,7,8]`

Answer (score 5):

If `self.var` is a [mutable sequence](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types), it will return a [shallow copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy) of that sequence.

If `self.var` is an immutable [built-in sequence](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange) such as a `string` or a `tuple`, most implementations will return `self.var` itself.

Comment: -1 If var refers to a **mutable** sequence, it will return a **reference to** a shallow copy of that sequence. If var refers to an immutable sequence (e.g. str, unicode, tuple), it should (for efficiency) return the original reference.

Comment: @John, the first part of your comment is technically right, but I'm not sure about the second part (see the last link in my answer). Also, I think the questioner is more interested by what the code actually *does* instead of what it *should* do :)

Comment: Amplification of "should": Second case with CPython will return original reference for built-in objects (because the implementers aren't silly). No such guarantee for user-defined objects. "Shared slice" (your last link) is irrelevant in the `[:]` case which is already "shared" by non-silly implementations.

Answer (score 2):

That will create a shallow copy of the list, and return it.

"Shallow copy", as opposed to "deep copy", means the list will only create new copies of the references in it, not the actual objects. That is, a new list with the same object references will be created, but the objects themselves will remain the same.

If you remove an item from the original the new list won't be affected, but if you alter one of the elements *inside* the original list (by calling a method or setting an object property, for example), the element will also change on the new list, because although they are different lists, they point to the same objects.

Comment: Who says it's a list? It could be any object that supports the slicing operation e.g. an xlm.etree.ElementTree.Element object

Comment: Of course, you're right. I could have said "any object that implements slicing functionality", but I think it would've hardly helped -- not the point of the question, to my understanding, I think the shallow vs. deep copy issue was the important part.

Answer (score 2):

It's called list slicing:

[from:to:skip]

[from:to]

So if I say:

```
list = range(20)
print list[1:3] #returns [2, 3]
print list[1:12:3] #returns [2, 5, 8, 11]
print list[14:] #because theres no end: [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
print list[14:-2] #-2 from the end: [15, 16, 17]
```

Comment: It's called slicing, an operation provided by several different types of objects.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the operators with a list the following ways:

list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

with a single : in the middle of the brackets you define the range from which position to what position to choose (starting position is 0. so I have the following options

list[0:3] shows [1,2,3], cause it starts from the position of the first number and it ends on the position previous to the second number

list[:3] shows the same than before, the first number is absent so there is no beginning limit

list[5:] shows the list from the fifth position to the end [6,7,8,9]

Now if x or y from  list[x,y] is negative then it starts if is x from the x position and if it is y it ends from len(list)-2 position
For example: list[-1:3]= [2,3]

Now you can have 2 :  like [x:y:z] here x indicates the starting cell, y the last cell (which is not included in the range returned) and z the step at which the sequence advances
list[0:5:2]=[0,2,4]